# Find exponental function for given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, exponential-function

I am trying to find a function corresponding to the following sequence:

```
3, 9, 21, 45, 93, 189, ...
```

I am measuring the number of recursive calls of a function where I call the function three times in every iteration, so I would expect it to be an exponential function.

If it is, how could I proceed to find it ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Comment: I could find a fifth degree polynomial giving those values at $1$, $2$,... and many other functions doing the same. If you *know* it's supposed to be an exponential function, the number of functions decrease a lot.

Comment: I am measuring the number of recursive calls of a function where I do call the function three times in every iteration.

Comment: Thats why i thought it would be exponential.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Note that $9-3=6,$ $21-9=12,$ $45-21=24,$ $93-45=48,$ and so on. Does that get you there?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a recursive function ?

Comment: You can certainly proceed that way, and you should be able to find a closed form. Let me know if you get stuck, or just want to check if your answer is correct.

Comment: I think I got it now :)

Comment: The function for 6, 12, 24, ... is 6 * 2^n-1 and now I just have to subtract 3

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Nicely done. You're very welcome! One slight refinement you might make is to note that $6=3\cdot 2,$ so that the formula becomes $3\cdot 2^n-3,$ which is perhaps a bit nicer.